# Given 4 line equation of a convex quadrilateral, how can I find coordinate of 4 corner?

Tags: matlab, geometry, 2d, computational-geometry

I have four line equations y=mx+b and there is 6 intersections point.

It is known that those line form a convex quadrilateral.

How can I find which four intersection form the quadrilateral (preferably in order)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Concave QUAD:**

[image: concave]

The 6th intersection point should be also in `1)` I just forget to draw it there.

1. **compute all the intersection points and pair them to lines**

   ```
   l1: p2,p5,p6
   l2: p1,p4,p6
   l3: p1,p2,p3
   l4: p3,p4,p5
   ```

   `l` means line and `p` means intersection point
2. **determine if point is only edge or also middle**

   so middle point is if you got another point from each side of line it belongs. In other words if you convert point to its parameter position (or distance from some start point) then middle point is in between the other two points distances. The parameter/distance you directly obtain while intersection computation but in case you don't you can use this:

   ```
   t(p) = dot(p-A,B-A)
   ```

   where `A,B` are line endpoints, p is queried intersection point and `t(p)` is its scalar "distance" from `A`.

   So find out which points are only edge `e` and which are middle `m`:

   ```
   l1: e2,e5,m6
   l2: e1,e4,m6
   l3: e1,m2,e3
   l4: e3,m4,e5
   ```

   now if any point is at least once middle then it is partially middle, if it is only edge then it is edge and if it is only middle then it is middle:

   ```
   edge:    p1,p3,p5
   partial: p2,p4
   middle:  p6
   ```
3. **construct polygon**

   So the edge points we have to use. The partial points we skip (as they lie on already used line) and finally we also use middle point. We know our polygon will be:

   ```
   (p1,p3,p5) + (p6)
   ```

   Now we need to find where the concave middle point `p6` will go. There are 3 combinations:

   ```
   e1,m6,e3,e5
   e1,e3,m6,e5
   e1,e3,e5,m6
   ```

   we know that `m6` belong to `l1,l2` and `l1,l2` has also `p2,p5,p1,p4` from which are edge points only: `e1,e5` so the `m6` will be placed between them so the correct solution is:

   ```
   e1,e3,e5,m6
   ```

**Now Convex QUAD:**

if we take advantage from **#1,#2** then to form convex quad we have to use the middle and partial middle points and chose one of the pure edge points. Select the one that is not belong to line with pure middle point. So we have to use:

```
    (p2,p4) + (m6) + one_from(e1,e3,e5)
```

the `m6` is not belonging to `l3,l4` so we need find edge belonging to both which is `e3` so

```
    (p2,p4) + (m6) + (e3)
```

Now we just have to find out the order. middle point and edge point will not be near themselves so you got 2 solutions:

```
    p2,m6,p4,e3
    p2,e3,p4,m6
```

Both are correct they are just reverse of themselves (differend polygon winding rule) so you can chose the one you need based on `z` coordinate of cross product of any two neighboring vertices.

[image: convex]

Answer (score 0):

Solve systems of linear equations for every line pair

```
  y = m[i] * x + b[i]
  y = m[j] * x + b[j]
```

where m[i], b[i] are coefficients of i-th line and get (x,y) for intersection.

If there are exactly 6 intersection (no parallel lines, no degeneracies), then every line has three intersection points in row. Two intersections are "outer" and one (middle) is "inner", so there are three inner and three outer points.

Seems that convex quadrilateral always contains all the three inner points, so we can separate inner points, and get corresponding fourth point.

For example, if lines are designated as A,B,C,D, and intersections AB, AC, CD are inner, then fourth point is intersection BD (B and D are unique in intersection list)

P.S. Note that line equation form `y=mx+b` is not suitable for all possible lines (not for vertical lines), so it would better to use [more general form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Forms_for_two-dimensional_linear_equations) like `A*x + B*y + C = 0` or other.

Comment: I know how to find the intersection point, can you elaborate on "Then sort calculated vertices by polar angle from arbitrary chosen vertex.", also there are 6 intersection point, how do I know which to pick

Comment: Ugh, I assumed that unique polar angles from the left bottom point at your picture are for needed vertices using the closest one when angle is the same, but i see that it does not work for arbitrary base vertex